# Add item to carousel before animation

Tags: jquery, carousel

I've setup a codepen from a simple carousel script taken from https://gist.github.com/dongyuwei/5864686

[image]

Basically, it will have 3 slides and and show 3 slides at a time but you can cycle through them infinitely.

The issue I'm having is that when the next or prev buttons are used, the sliding animation occurs and once completed the end slide is moved which looks really clunky.

Is there a way to have the slide on the end, duplicated to the required position, then do the slide animation and then remove the old one for a cleaner result?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/mellomedia/pen/WxBXjX

```
$('.infinite-carousel').infiniteCarousel({
  itemsPerMove : 1,
  duration : 500
});
```

Comment: use duration -5s for smooth slide - $('.infinite-carousel').infiniteCarousel({
  itemsPerMove : 1,
  duration : 5
});

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/AXkbQN

Comment: Thanks Naga but how do you do this without removing the sliding animation effect?

Comment: updated codepen... check it once

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use carousel duration as 50

```
$('.infinite-carousel').infiniteCarousel({
  itemsPerMove : 1,
  duration : 50
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/AXkbQN

Comment: Hi Naga, is there a way to still keep a smooth transition (500) and have the item added in without appearing all of a sudden?